# Como extrair determinado índice dentro deste array com um for?

Tags: php, array

Gostaria de extrair todas os indíces `[Foto]` deste array mas ainda não compreendo corretamente como fazer isso pois ainda estou lutando com o aprendizado de `array multidimensionais`. O que eu consegui fazer foi extrair **1 foto** assim:

```
echo $fotos = $result['Foto'][1]['Foto'];
```

**Pergunta:** Como dentro de um `for` eu consigo extrair todas os índices `[Foto]`?

O array é este:

```
Array
(
    [Codigo] => 67
    [Foto_Codigo] => 7
    [Foto] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Codigo] => 1
                    [Foto] => http://static.vista.s3.amazonaws.com/danielbo/vista.imobi/fotos/67/ik5u4v_6756311964c945c.jpg
                    [FotoPequena] => http://static.vista.s3.amazonaws.com/danielbo/vista.imobi/fotos/67/ik5u4v_6756311964c945c_p.jpg
                    [Destaque] => Sim
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Codigo] => 2
                    [Foto] => http://static.vista.s3.amazonaws.com/danielbo/vista.imobi/fotos/67/ik5u4v_6756311963961c5.jpg
                    [FotoPequena] => http://static.vista.s3.amazonaws.com/danielbo/vista.imobi/fotos/67/ik5u4v_6756311963961c5_p.jpg
                    [Destaque] => Nao
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [Codigo] => 3
                    [Foto] => http://static.vista.s3.amazonaws.com/danielbo/vista.imobi/fotos/67/ik5u4v_6756311964e6f0b.jpg
                    [FotoPequena] => http://static.vista.s3.amazonaws.com/danielbo/vista.imobi/fotos/67/ik5u4v_6756311964e6f0b_p.jpg
                    [Destaque] => Nao
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [Codigo] => 4
                    [Foto] => http://static.vista.s3.amazonaws.com/danielbo/vista.imobi/fotos/67/ik5u4v_6756311965dd324.jpg
                    [FotoPequena] => http://static.vista.s3.amazonaws.com/danielbo/vista.imobi/fotos/67/ik5u4v_6756311965dd324_p.jpg
                    [Destaque] => Nao
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [Codigo] => 5
                    [Foto] => http://static.vista.s3.amazonaws.com/danielbo/vista.imobi/fotos/67/ik5u4v_6756311965cc92b.jpg
                    [FotoPequena] => http://static.vista.s3.amazonaws.com/danielbo/vista.imobi/fotos/67/ik5u4v_6756311965cc92b_p.jpg
                    [Destaque] => Nao
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [Codigo] => 6
                    [Foto] => http://static.vista.s3.amazonaws.com/danielbo/vista.imobi/fotos/67/ik5u4v_67563119654e991.jpg
                    [FotoPequena] => http://static.vista.s3.amazonaws.com/danielbo/vista.imobi/fotos/67/ik5u4v_67563119654e991_p.jpg
                    [Destaque] => Nao
                )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazê-lo de diversas maneiras diferentes, todas com o mesmo resultado:

#### Com `foreach`:

Nesse caso dispensamos o índice de cada foto e já recebemos diretamente o *sub-array*:

```
$fotos = [];
foreach ($array['Foto'] as $foto) {
    $fotos[] = $foto['Foto'];
}
```

#### Com `for`:

A única ressalva nesse código é que o índice inicial é `1`, e não `0`; por isso precisamos gerar um novo *array* cujos índices começam com `0`, para que o percorramos sem problemas no `for`:

```
$fotosAnterior = array_values($array['Foto']);
$fotos = [];
for ($i=0; $i<count($fotosAnterior); $i++) {
    $fotos[] = $array['Foto'][$i]['Foto'];
}
```

#### Com `array_map`:

Código mais curto, porém um pouco mais difícil de entender para iniciantes. A ideia é mapear cada item do *array* de fotos a um retorno – no caso, o próprio valor do item `Foto`:

```
$fotos = array_map(function(array $foto) {
    return $foto['Foto'];
}, $array);
```